# Where do I learn about IP blocks and subnets? Or is there just a calculator that does it all for me?

Tags: networking, iptables, ip, subnet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work)

Amazon's elastic compute tool (among others) requires the ip block format for their command:

```
ec2-authorize websrv -P tcp -p 80 -s 205.192.0.0/16
```

I may be doing this wrong, but as far as I can tell I need to use the block format even for a single IP address. 1) So, how would I do that for this IP?

```
71.75.232.132
```

Several years ago I took a CCNA class, and I remember going over IPs and subnets, masks, broadcast addresses, class a/b/c networks, etc. However a lot seems to have changed since then - for example I don't think you can tell what "class" a network is in just by looking at it anymore - sometimes they could be multiple classes.

2) Anyhow, my second question is where do I go to get a refresher on all these things?

3) Or should I just be using `ipcalc` or an online calculator to do it all for me - and if so, which one?

Comment: [This is probably the best explanation of subnets you can find here.](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For the single IP, you can say "71.75.232.132/32".

2) and 3) You can google for CIDR.  You will see the wikipedia page on CIDR, which should have something about subnetting to refresh your memor, and should have a calculator pretty high up in search results.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in a pinch...

http://subnetmask.info/

http://www.skullbox.net/subnetcalculator.php